# How can I create a search box redirecting to a page?

Tags: forms

I'm trying to create a shipment tracker in my website that will use a third party service to search.
I want to program this form so that upon pressing "submit" it directs customers to: http://example.com/VALUEINSERTEDINTHEBOX

I unsuccessfully used this:

```
  <form method="get"> <input type="text" class="Search" name="search" value="<%=h params[:search] %>"> <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="submit" value="Search"><br><br></form>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Customer inputs a tracking number in the form / search box eg (123456)
2. Upon pressing "submit", customer gets redirected to a extenal site: **http://example.com/123456**

Any help is much appreciated.